# Schmitt trigger Upper and Lower Threshold voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, schmitt-trigger

I speak with reference to [this (Electrical4u - blog tutorial)](https://www.electrical4u.com/schmitt-trigger/) and [this (All about electronics - video tutorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-ohKRWeod4) on the Schmitt trigger.

From what I have understood,
in the non-inverting schmitt Trigger,

- When Vin > Vut the output is High (Vout = VH)
- When Vin < Vlt the output is Low (Vout = VL)

And it is exactly the opposite in inverting Schmitt trigger,

- When Vin > Vut the output is Low(Vout = VL)
- When Vin < Vlt the output is High(Vout = VH)

where Vin --> Input Voltage, Vut --> Upper Threshold, Vlt -- Lower Threshold,Vout --> Output voltage.

Here in the picture shown,
[image]

The first line gives the output equation.
Here they assume that the output is in **high** state. Then they find the Vut as shown. Here is where my question is, for the inverting case the **output should be VL for Upper threshold**. But in the expression for the **Upper Threshold it is VH** (Voltage high or +Vsat). Why is it so?

Comment: Well, that's because of positive feedback and simply comes out from direct circuit analysis. Another good explanation with analysis and design steps is in https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa997a/snoa997a.pdf

Comment: I am sorry that I couldn't able to follow the resource you provided.  I understood that we make it Vh because after that the voltage turns towards -Vsat. So until that point it is in Vsat. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that when the comparator switches the output itself moves the reference point around. It's all basic circuit analysis after that, just do the math

Comment: Oh ok Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit acts like a comparator.
If you want to show VL at the output you have to push the input voltage over the threshold, because the "-" input shall be greater than the "+" input. The threshold to exceed is the voltage on the "+" input of the op-amp, that is the application of the Kirchhoff's voltage law.
Suppose that the output is in the high state:
$$V_{out} = V_H$$
then the voltage on the "-" input shall exceed the voltage on the "+" input, that is:
$$V_{UT} = {R_1\over{R_1+R_2}}\bullet V_H$$
This is why the upper voltage is used